Colab Document R Session connecting to BigQuery Permissions
I'm trying to use an R runtime in a Google Colab document to pull data from BigQuery. A forum suggested that I use the BigRQuery package, but I have some questions regarding what's actually being shared when I give permissions in the authentication process/flow.
Tidyverse API is pulled up when I run the code snippet below and it asks if I want to give it permission to read/write/view data in BigQuery, but I'm unsure where this is occurring? Is Tidyverse/RStudio viewing/storing this information or does it happen locally in the notebook? It feels like a lot of scope for what I'm trying to do...perhaps there's a way to pull the data from BigQuery into an R Colab runtime without this library?
Thanks for any and all information!!!
install.packages("bigrquery")
library(bigrquery)

# Project ID inserted based on the query results selected to explore
projectid = 'my-project-id' 

# variable that stores my sql statement
sql <- "
my sql statement
"

